# How to plot intermediate result from optimx package in R

Tags: r, package

I am using optimx package in R to minimize the value of a function. I would like to monitor the value of this function from time to time. But the function optimx seems to output the result only once after the whole process is done. Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Set the `trace` component of the `control` argument to a positive number to enable tracing.

```
optimx(...., control=list(trace=2))
```

Exactly how much output this produces depends on the method you've chosen, but in general the larger the number, the more output.